# Confusion regarding ThreadGroup#activeCount()

Tags: java, multithreading, threadgroup

The documentation for **ThreadGroup#activeCount()** says : **Returns an estimate of the number of active threads in this thread group and its subgroups.**
Does that count include threads in **sleep , wait and join** mode or only those threads which are executing **run** method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily try this:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.nextInt();
    }
});
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
t1.start();   // this will be RUNNABLE
t2.start();   // this will be TIMED_WAITING
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup().activeCount());
```

Prints 3. Commenting the lines

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

leads to printing 1.